# Abrir arquivo RTF utilizando o comando echo do PHP

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, rtf

Olá,
Tenho um arquivo em .rtf todo formatado certinho, porém quando tento usar a função echo/fopen no PHP para abri-lo na página web, ele vem todo bagunçado.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDw5Z.png)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá! O .rtf (Rich Text Format) é um formato de arquivo de texto com formatação, que pode ser lido por vários programas de processamento de texto. Quando você usa a função echo ou fopen para exibir o conteúdo do arquivo em uma página web, o navegador interpreta o conteúdo como HTML e pode gerar resultados inesperados, como texto formatado incorretamente ou código HTML mal formado.

Uma forma de exibir o conteúdo do arquivo .rtf na página web sem perder a formatação é convertê-lo para HTML. Você pode fazer isso usando uma biblioteca de conversão de .rtf para HTML, como a PHP RTF Parser (https://github.com/phi16/php-rtf-parser).

Para usar a biblioteca, basta incluir o arquivo de biblioteca em seu script PHP e chamar a função RtfHtml::parse passando o conteúdo do arquivo .rtf como argumento. A função retornará o conteúdo do arquivo em HTML, que você pode exibir na página web usando a função echo ou outra forma de saída de dados.

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php

// Inclui a biblioteca
require_once 'path/to/RtfHtml.php';

// Abre o arquivo .rtf
$rtf = file_get_contents('path/to/file.rtf');

// Converte o conteúdo do arquivo para HTML
$html = RtfHtml::parse($rtf);

// Exibe o conteúdo HTML na página
echo $html;
Espero que isso ajude! Qualquer dúvida adicional, sinta-se à vontade para perguntar.
```

Comment: Obrigada! te amo